# How to download easyBI report in PDF format?

Tags: python, api, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, easybind

I am using [this](https://my/server.com/plugins/servlet/eazybi/accounts/***/cubes/Issues/reports/****.pdf) API to download PDF report of easyBI dashboard but I get this error only for PDF format but working fine with CSV and XLS.

```
Please visit the eazyBI for Jira installation and setup documentation page and check setup instructions or see the Troubleshooting section for the log files location.
```

I tried automating it with selenium web driver to capture URL as PDF. But in this method we need to authenticate for every request made.

Answer (score 0):

For some chart types, eazyBI requires headless Google Chrome installation on Server/Data Center to export them as PDFs with the report results export API - https://docs.eazybi.com/eazybi/set-up-and-administer/customization/report-results-export-api. See the necessary steps here - https://docs.eazybi.com/eazybi/set-up-and-administer/atlassian-server-and-data-center/export-to-pdf.